# Can I transform Westvale Abbey during either assign attackers or assign blockers phase

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Wanting to know if it is possible to sacrifice creatures during assign attackers or assign blockers in order to transform [Westvale Abbey](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWestvale%20Abbey%5d) and use him as an attacker or blocker.  It would also require taping lands to generate the mana required or maybe artifacts.

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/41689/warkite-marauder-and-the-timing-for-its-effect

Comment: You can also block with the 5 sacrifices and prevent the damage (and any lifelink) from the attackers if they dont have trample.

Answer (score 5):

**You can transform Westvale Abbey at several points of the Combat phase and potentially use Ormendahl as an attacker or blocker.**

The Abbey's abilities other than its mana ability are normal activated abilities that require you to have priority.

There are 5 steps to combat:

> 506.1. The combat phase has five steps, which proceed in order: beginning of combat, declare attackers, declare blockers, combat damage, and end of combat.

During beginning of combat, everyone gets priority in APNAP order and you can transform Westvale Abbey. This is your last chance to transform if you want Ormendahl as an attacker this turn, and the other players will still get the opportunity to play instant spells and abilities after the Abbey has transformed.

> 507. Beginning of Combat Step
>
> 507.2. Second, the active player gets priority.

After everyone has passed priority, attackers are declared. If you are the attacking player, you can declare Ormendahl as an attacking creature if you controlled the permanent (Abbey/Ormendahl) uninterrupted since the  beginning of your turn, i.e. it has no summoning sickness. Directly afterwards, players again have the opportunity to cast spells and activate abilities. If you want Ormendahl as a blocker, now is your last chance to transform the Abbey.

> 508. Declare Attackers Step
>
> 508.1. First, the active player declares attackers. [..]
>
> 508.2. Second, the active player gets priority. [..]

Note that this means that as soon as the declare attackers step has started, anything that isn't already a creature cannot be declared to attack, and it's too late to transform the Abbey.

Next, blockers are declared (including another round of priority). Again, anything that isn't already a creature can't be declared a blocker.

> 509. Declare Blockers Step
>
> 509.1. First, the defending player declares blockers.
>
> 509.4. Fourth, the active player gets priority.

Finally, damage is dealt and combat ends.

Comment: "You can use mana abilities whenever you like" is inaccurate. If you don't have priority, the only way to activate mana abilities is if you are doing so as part casting a spell or activating an ability.

Comment: Minor nitpick, Ormendahl has haste so the summoning sickness thing doesn't matter.

Comment: @GendoIkari I agree with your nitpick, but am confused by your second sentence - if you don't have priority, how are you casting a spell or activating an ability to begin with?

Comment: @NuclearWang No one has priority while in the process of casting a spell; you had priority when you started to cast the spell. Also, I was slightly incorrect, you can also activate a mana ability when a rule or effect asks for a mana payment, which could be things other than your own spells/abilities (Brainwash, Mana Leak).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to attack with [Ormendahl, Profane Prince](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOrmendahl%2c%20Profane%20Prince%5d), you need to transform [Westvale Abbey](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWestvale%20Abbey%5d) before the declare attackers step, either in beginning of combat step or sooner.

If you want to block with Ormendahl, Profane Prince, you need to transform Westvale Abbey before the declare blockers step, either in declare attackers step or sooner.

In the declare attackers step, players get priority only after attackers are declared, so it would be too late. Similarly, in declare blockers step, players get priority only after blockers are declared.

> 508. Declare Attackers Step
>
> > 508.1. First, the active player declares attackers. [..]
> >
> > 508.2. Second, the active player gets priority. [..]
>
> 509. Declare Blockers Step
>
> > 509.1. First, the defending player declares blockers.
> >
> > 509.4. Fourth, the active player gets priority.